# How to save text or numbers to strings and make them counting points on a button click?

Tags: java, android

I know this question has been asked before but in my case it looks different. I have a TextView which has decimal numbers, these numbers changes every time. Below it I have a button, and when I click it, it should take the decimal number in the textview and add as points.

This is what I mean: the textview sometimes displays 0.3, if I click the button it should take this 0.3 and add it to points, if the textview is showing 0.8, the button should add that 0.8 to the points and the points accumulate. The following is what I have tried:

I have `MainActivity.class` and with this code in `onClick listener` of the button:

```
String getgPoints = (String)points.getText();
data.edit().putFloat("count", parseFloat(getPoints(preview.this) + getgPoints)).apply();
```

This is in my button click listener, it works but the problem is this: The points do not add but they are creating something a series of numbers, for example, if the textview is showing 0.3, and when I click the button my coin balance 0.3 at first click, 0.33 at second click, 0.333 at third click, and so on, but I do not want them to behave like that, I want them to add as from 0.3 on first click, 0.6 on second, 0.9 on third, 1.2 on fourth and so on.

So now my question is, how can I correct my code?

Comment: You are adding a string to a number. This automatically converts the number to a string and **appends** the second string to it. To perform **numeric** operations, you need **numbers**, not strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add float to float (you need to convert getgPoints to float before you can add it to another float):

```
String getgPoints = (String)points.getText();
data.edit().putFloat("count", parseFloat(getPoints(preview.this) + parseFloat(getgPoints))).apply();
```

Remember to catch NumberFormatException, if you can't guarantee that the text will always be formatted as a valid `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not parsing the second string to float

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you are saying Nino

Comment: Please show me the parseFloat code. I think the problem is this method

Comment: sorry, but your question is unclear to me as long as you don't post more code

Comment: My float code is:  public static float getPoints(Context context){
        return getSavedData(context).getFloat("count",0);
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
String s_number = points.getText().toString();
float f_number = Float.parseFloat(s_number);
//above is the parsing code
sum += f_number;
```

Here the string is parse into float.

Comment: Can you help me edit from the code that i sent Abhi, how do i modify to match the answer you have given me

Comment: s_number is the string got from textview. f_number is float got from after parsing string s_number. Now f_number can be added to points early stored or calculated